# how to use specific library when building application from source?

Tags: compiling, jpeg

I am trying to compile [jpegoptim](https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim)  from source . When I try to do ./configure I have the following error

```
Cannot find libjpeg or you have too old version (v6 or later required).
```

I wanted to make sure the existence of `libjpeg.so`

```
ldconfig -p | grep libjpeg
```

There are four versions of the library in my system

```
libjpeg.so.62 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
libjpeg.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
libjpeg.so.8 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
libjpeg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so

dpkg -l | grep 'libjpeg.*-dev'

ii  libjpeg-dev:amd64                   8c-2ubuntu8                                                     amd64       Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libjpeg-turbo8-dev:amd64            1.3.0-0ubuntu2                                      amd64        Development files for the IJG JPEG library
ii  libjpeg8-dev:amd64                  8c-2ubuntu8                                         amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
```

How do use the libjpeg.so.8 to build jpegoptim?

Comment: Which (if any) jpeg *development* packages are installed? Please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg -l | grep 'libjpeg.*-dev'`

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on my machine, install `libjpeg62-dev`, that's all:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev
```

---

```
dpkg -l | grep 'libjpeg.*-dev'
ii  libjpeg62-dev:amd64  1:6b2-2  amd64  Development files for the IJG JPEG library (version 6.2)

ldconfig -p | grep libjpeg
    libjpeg.so.62 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
    libjpeg.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
    libjpeg.so.8 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
    libjpeg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
```